# -nan error when finding an average in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that calculates the average within the range -30 to 150, and throws out any bad numbers that are not in this range. The terminating number is -999. When entering -999 as the only number, it throws an error in my average.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

int main(){

    // I defined my variables before entering the do while loop
    int invalid_temps {0};
    double valid_temps {0.0};
    int temp {};
    double average {0.0};
    double sum_of_temps {0.0};

    /*  I need the prompt to show at least once, so I used a do while loop.
    I also just wanted some practice using the do while loop. */
    do {
        std::cout << "Enter a temperature (-999 to quit): ";
        std::cin >> temp;
        /* I used an if statement keep track of valid and invalid outputs. It also helped me manipulate what numbers would be included in the average. */
        if (temp >= -30 && temp <= 150){
            valid_temps++;
            sum_of_temps += temp;
        } else {
            invalid_temps++;
        }
    } while (temp != -999);
    average = sum_of_temps / valid_temps;
    /* Here I subtract one from the overall total of my invalid temps, so it doesn't include the 
    terminating number, -999. */
    invalid_temps -= 1;

    // Output
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    std::cout << "\nAverage Temperature: " << average << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::defaultfloat;
    std::cout << "# of Invalid Temperatures: " << invalid_temps << std::endl;
    std::cout << "# of Valid Temperatures: " << valid_temps << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result from me entering only -999 is:

```
Average Temperature: -nan
# of Invalid Temperatures: 0
# of Valid Temperatures: 0
```

How do I make it show 0.000 and not -nan? Thanks!

Comment: `if (std::isnan(average)) average = 0.0;`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `if(isnan(average)) ...` ? But to me, it does not make sense to display 0 instead of NaN. Better something like `-` or `No data`.

Comment: Check if you're dividing by zero before performing the operation and print something else like, "No valid input."

Comment: Hmm, what is the average of no number? Is it really 0? If the average were 0 so far, and I add any another number to it (not 0), what is the average then? Certainly not that number.

Comment: What is the result of dividing by 0?

Comment: `average = (valid_temps ? sum_of_temps / valid_temps : 0.0);`

Comment: `average = sum_of_temps / valid_temps;` -- What if there are no valid temperatures?  You are dividing by `0.0`.

Comment: Another way of approaching your issue in C++, which will also check not to divide by 0.0 : https://onlinegdb.com/a6l4Nsg5i

Comment: If there’s no data, don’t calculate the (meaningless) average.

Answer (score 3):

You've gotten several answers and comments that aren't right. The problem isn't simply  division by zero; that alone doesn't create a `nan`. `3.0 / 0.0` is `inf`, infinity. The problem comes from dividing zero by zero. When there is no valid input, `sum_of_temps` is 0 and `valid_temps` is 0, so `sum_of_temps / valid_temps` is `nan`, i.e., Not a Number. If you think of dividing `a/b` as asking the question "what number, multiplied by `b`, gives me `a`?" it should be clearer. The answer to that question is **any number** multiplied by 0 gives 0. Since there is no single value, the result is `nan`.

To avoid displaying `nan`, if there’s no data, don’t calculate the (meaningless) average. Show an appropriate message instead.

Comment: Good explanation! You got my vote. Taking it to the next step, do you have any advice in response the OP's question, "How do I _make it show 0.000_ and not -nan?"

Answer (score -1):

This error typically occurs when there are invalid or unexpected values involved in the calculation, such as dividing by zero or encountering uninitialized variables. To troubleshoot, ensure that all variables used in the calculation are properly initialized and that any division operations account for potential zero denominators.